# VIC cipher author known?

Tags: reference-request, classical-cipher, history

Does anybody know if the design of VIC cipher is attributed to anybody? I've tried Google and found nothing. There are quite a few sites describing the method in detail, a few implementing it programmatically, and ample stories of the code in the coin, but who actually came up with it? Who decided to put the ideas together in that way? Some Russian scientist I assume, but does anybody know who?

Comment: I have tried pretty hard to find out, but have had no luck.  The answer is inside an archive somewhere in a basement in Russia, and perhaps it is still classified.

Answer (score -2):

Russian spy Reino Häyhänen, code name VICTOR;
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIC_cipher

Comment: He was the first one caught by USA "using" the cipher. Probably some unknown Russian mathematician came up with it. He might be known by name in Russian mathematician circles.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read that the question said *design*. Seemed a little obvious...